# Apache Ignite high data availability - partitional & backup setup

Tags: ignite

I run Apache Ignite to store large data set for computation & retrieval. For now I am trying to see if in-memory itself can address the caching problem.

I have partitioned the cache & set the backup count to 1. I believe, the data will be copied to another node to address any failure, this means, any one of the node goes down, the respective data should be available from the backup node. So, querying the cache should not be affected.

In my setup, when I shutdown one of the node, the data becomes unavailable & query to the cache returns null. Below is my ignite setup (run locally). What's the right way to configure the partition with right backup to address any node failures?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
<bean abstract="true" id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <!-- Set to true to enable distributed class loading for examples, default is false. -->
    <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true" />

    <property name="rebalanceThreadPoolSize" value="4" />
    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="mycache" />
                <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED" />
                <property name="backups" value="1" />
                <property name="rebalanceMode" value="SYNC" />
                <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="FULL_SYNC" />
                <property name="partitionLossPolicy" value="READ_ONLY_SAFE" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>

    <!-- Enable task execution events for examples. -->
    <property name="includeEventTypes">
        <list>
            <!--Task execution events-->
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_STARTED" />
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FINISHED" />
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FAILED" />
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_TIMEDOUT" />
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_SESSION_ATTR_SET" />
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_REDUCED" />

            <!--Cache events-->
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT" />
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_READ" />
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_REMOVED" />
        </list>
    </property>

    <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                    <property name="addresses">
                        <list>
                            <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                            <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Could you share Ignite log file? How do you create that cache?

Comment: I just started the server using this command `./ignite.sh`

Comment: Yes, but the default configuration doesn't define any caches or remove nodes from topology.  I mean it's unclear what's happening to the grid. My assumption with the provided info is the same as yours - backup copies should be treated as primary ones.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your nodes are a part of the same cluster. You should see info in the logs that the topology includes multiple servers.

Your understanding of the cache configuration is correct - the data should be available after one node goes down. Moreover, with the `READ_ONLY_SAFE` policy you cannot silently lose data even if the cluster doesn't have enough copies - your cache reads would start throwing errors.

Since you're getting `null` I'm guessing that your client just reconnected to the second server, which is not connected to the first one (and is therefore empty).